# Baking after rising

Tags: bread, rising

I have risen my dinner rolls a second time. Now they have plumped up in their baking pan. How quickly do I need to bake the bread once the bread has risen a second time?

Comment: It depends on the size of the rolls, and the temperature of the oven. You are usually looking at around 25-30 mins at 400F

Comment: Do you mean how long must they bake, or how long can you wait until you begin to bake?

Answer (score 2):

Once you have gotten the bread to rise a second time, you want to get it in the oven ASAP after it has risen to the level you want.  You could always deflate it, and let it rerise, if you've gone past what you wanted, but your yeast may not have enough energy to go a third time.